# Switch between X applications without a window manager

Tags: debian, x11, window, window-management

I currently have a Java application that interacts with a web application.

The Java application is launched first and becomes a full screen application; then `chromium-browser` is launched on top of it and also becomes a full screen application.

I would like to be able to switch back and forth between these two applications.

Is there a way to be able to go back and forth between making these applications visible / the top most using only X and not using a window manager? I don't have a lot of resources for running a typically full-featured window manager.

**Machine Info:**
Linux Debian 8 i386, single monitor, single display, 4GB disk, 2GB RAM, no swap

```
$ xdpyinfo | grep version
   version number:    11.0
   X.Org version: 1.16.4
```

---

I've tried using `wmctrl` and `xdotools` but you need a window manager for those. I keep getting errors such as

> Your windowmanager claims not to support _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW, so the attempt to query the active window aborted.
>   xdo_get_active_window reported an error

and

> Cannot get client list properties. 
>   (_NET_CLIENT_LIST or _WIN_CLIENT_LIST)

Comment: Can't you use a very light window manager like Openbox or i3wm?

Comment: If it's absolutely necessary, and takes up less than 1MB of space, I can. I've tried 9wm, lwm and xmonad, but I have not had any luck.

Comment: What did not work about those? Have you tried `dwm`? Without a Window manager of some kind it will be more difficult to manage your X windows in the manner you described. There are solutions but you will need to install software and at a limit of less than 1 MB of space that will severely limit your options.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need a window manager. If you can run Chromium, you can run a lightweight window manager. I'd qualify Openbox, i3wm and xmonad as medium-weight. There are plenty of lighter ones; I don't have a particular recommendation, but do browse [the comprehensive list](https://www.gilesorr.com/wm/table.html) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_X_window_managers).

Comment: If you have a limit of 1 MB, you can try to write your own window manager that does nothing except switch between those applications. Have a look at `XRaiseWindow`. How do you want to switch? With a special key sequence?

Comment: @dirkt a key sequence is what I'm looking for. Before I was running two x servers, each on their own VT to switch back and fourth vita alt+[Function key of VT] --(The internet said this was very inefficient and I saw performance problems with this). Since I'm used to alt+F* a key sequence would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by using a small package called alttab: https://github.com/katcaola/alttab

To run it with no window manager, you call it with the flags `alttab -w 0`.

You can either build/compile the source, or you can install via apt-get ([See install instructions here](https://github.com/katcaola/alttab/blob/master/INSTALL.md)) and be sure to read the [window manager setup page](https://github.com/katcaola/alttab/blob/master/doc/wm-setup.md).